# Pasrse API Response CSV to List without writing to file

Tags: python, csv, geocoding

Goal:

- Directly read .csv API response to Python list

I am using the Census Bureau's Bulk [Geocoder](http://geocoding.geo.census.gov/geocoder/geographies/addressbatch?form) to get the lat/long of many addresses. The [documentation](http://geocoding.geo.census.gov/geocoder/Geocoding_Services_API.pdf) for Batch Geocoding is on page 5-6.

I would like to be able to read this csv to a list without first saving the file.

My first attempt was to do the following:

Get response:

```
    import requests
    import csv

    url = 'http://geocoding.geo.census.gov/geocoder/locations/addressbatch'
    payload = {'benchmark':'Public_AR_Current', 'vintage':'Current_Current', 'returntype':'locations'}
    files = {'addressFile':('Addresses.csv',open(tmp_file,'rb'),'text/csv')}
    response = requests.post(url,data=payload,files=files)
```

Handle response (without writing to file):

```
    reader = csv.reader(response.content)
    tmp_list = list(reader)

    print(tmp_list)
```

The output is a 1-D list:

> [[unique_id], [input_address], [match/no_match], [exact/non-exact], [output_address], [lat/long], [tiger_line_id], [tiger_line_side], [ ], .... ]

The newline is being read as an element to be put into the list (shown as [ ]).

However, if I do the following:

Handle response (first writing response to file):

```
    with open('out.csv','w') as f:
        f.write(response.content)

    with open('out.csv','rb') as r:
        reader = csv.reader(r)
        tmp_list = list(reader)

    print(tmp_list)
```

The output for this method is the desired 2-D list of lists:

> [[unique_id, input_address, match/no_match, exact/non-exact, output_address, lat/long, tiger_line_id, tiger_line_side], .... ]

How can I read the .csv response directly to a list? I would like to avoid I/O operations because I may be performing 300+ batches at a time (which would be 300+ write to file/read from file.

Comment: looks like you are already doing it without writing to file, the response just might need some cleaning before using csvreader.  Can you post some of the raw response?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`csv.reader`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader) class accepts an iterable of *lines*; if you split the content by lines before passing it in it should work:

```
reader = csv.reader(response.content.split('\n'))
```